# Difference-in-Differences setup for policy evalution

Tags: difference-in-difference

I have a panel data set of housing prices from different neighborhoods in a city - and wish to test whether or not a policy has had an impact on the housing prices. The policy (treatment) is simply a sign signaling whether it is a good or bad neighborhood (based on parameters which are already known).

Initially I figured I could mirror the paper by Card and Krueger (1994) with a difference-in-differences estimation however what complicates my issue is that the policy enables neighborhoods to go from good-bad and bad-good over a span of 10 years. So they could potentially get a treatment multiple times.

Any suggestions into papers which has studied policies in a similar fashion or at methods which could be applied is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Treatment is allowed to switch on and off, but the issue you have is some neighborhoods start out in the “treated” condition (i.e., “good” status). I assume you care about the neighborhoods that transform from “bad” neighborhoods to “good” neighborhoods *over time*, maybe because of better parks, more policing, et cetera. Right?

Comment: @ThomaBilach not exactly. I have data from before the policy is enabled (pre-treatment) and after the policy is enabled. The neighborhooods that becomes "bad" the moment is enabled is obviously the same as before - they simply have a label on now. I'm looking to evaluate the effect of this label (the policy).

Comment: So the policy is the labeling scheme. Do some neighborhoods have no labels?

Comment: Basicly the policy labels all neighborhoods which are deemed bad as bad - the remaining neighborhoods are considered "good" or "neutral" or something similar.

Comment: So what's the goal of the study? Do you want to compare the "good" versus the "bad" neighborhoods? What comparisons do you want to make? And lastly, can the signage in one neighborhood switch back and forth from "good" to "bad" over time?